# ListView opening a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview

this is a more design centric question. But I was thinking of developing an app which will have a ListView containing arrays of for example, coffee names.

Now when the user clicks on a coffee name, I want to have a detailed info page on the coffee style and how to make it. Basically just imagine a new window with a lot of info.

My main question is, do you think that the best way to do this is to open a new activity on click in the ListView? I am new to Android so I am not sure if there is a simpler way to do this.

Thanks to anybody that can help!

Comment: Yes, a new activity is good. It's also good to start using Fragment at the beginning or your app development.

Comment: though fragments can be pretty neat if you are a greenhorn in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, creating a new activity on the click of the list item is the right approach to do so.

Comment: So if I were to have 20 different variants all containing information. I would have to have a different class for each variety? I am assuming I can just use the same XML layout for each though.

Comment: I guess a single class will do. I  mean you will be displaying the information in the same format. Its just that the information will be different. So you can use switch case statement to set different info in a textView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new and your customer is new too, than thats the way: open a detail page , a new activity (detail.xml layout) and fill it with the selected coffe.

If your customer want a fancy app and be on the top of ... than he will ask for you to present an [ExpandableList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), it also depends on the application too.

Answer (score 0):

In my current app, I created my listview within a fragment. I would set a listener inside the fragment and this would pass all my data as so to a new activity.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //goes to new activity passing the item name
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            //get text for current item
            String textGet = mylist1.get(position);

            //put text into a bundle and add to intent
            intent.putExtra("text", textGet);

            //get position to carry integer
            intent.putExtra("position", position);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            //begin other activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```